# How do I find the most similar string from list

Tags: java, list, design-patterns

I have a list of strings in random format:

```
AppName-ver-1.1.0-data.exe
AppName-ver-1.1.1-secondData.exe
AppName-ver-1.2.0-data.exe
AppName-ver-1.2.1-data.exe
AppName-ver-1.2.3-data.exe
AnotherAppName-ver-1.0.0-data.exe
AnotherAppName-ver-1.0.0-secondData.exe
```

What would be an efficient way in java to find the closest value to string:

```
AppName-ver-1.2.4-data.exe
```

UPD: closest - by the naming not length so AppName-ver-1.2.3-data.exe is the expected result

Comment: So what is the closest string to **AppName-ver-1.2.4-data.exe** from your list? and why? all this context should be mentioned!

Comment: I think the most difficult part is answering "what do you mean by closest". Once you have that answer, the rest of the code is easy.

Comment: by the name. length shouldn't be calculated (AppName-ver-1.2.3-data.exe is expected)

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize what commenters already pointed out:

If you define 'closest' to be the string length, then
`AppName-ver-1.2.4-data.exe` has the value 26, and

```
AppName-ver-1.1.0-data.exe
AppName-ver-1.2.0-data.exe
AppName-ver-1.2.1-data.exe
AppName-ver-1.2.3-data.exe
```

all resemble 26 as well so they are a direct match.

You could also define 'closest' to have the least [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). This will give completely different results and `AppName-ver-1.2.0-data.exe` might win as it is just one bit off.